# Understanding what default styles are used in a Flutter + Material app

Tags: flutter, dart, material-design, flutter-theme

Just starting out with Flutter + Material design. I notice that when a create a theme using ThemeData, if I use something like this:

```dart
ThemeData(
  textTheme: TextTheme(bodyText1: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
)
```

It doesn't seem to colour the text in a simple GridView with Text widgets with the colour white. However, if I change the above to use `bodyText2` it does.

What is the logic behind `bodyText2` being used for text across the app? Is there a good place to reference which text style names get used and why in a theming situation? Is this all just knowledge acquired through trial-and-error or are there some good catch-all rules for which styles get used in which circumstances?

Thanks.

Comment: You can read the specifications and details here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextTheme-class.html

Comment: Yeah I've seen that breakdown. This gives a good _what_ but not a very good _why_. I get that different names map to different font specs; what is not so obvious is what defaults are used throughout the application itself. Why does changing ` `bodyText2` and not `bodyText1` seem to be used in my widgets? Can I be certain that `bodyText2` will always be used if I don't pick a specific text theme at the local level? The answers to these questions seem absent from the documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update**: If using 2021 styles, not 2018 styles, swap [bodyText2](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextTheme/bodyText2.html) (2018 style), for [bodyMedium](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextTheme/bodyMedium.html)  (2021 style).
**End update.**

I ran into the same issue and did some research on this.

As per the official documentation for [`Text`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html)  :

> The style argument is optional. When omitted, the text will use the style from the closest enclosing `DefaultTextStyle`.

And the explanation for [bodyText2](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextTheme/bodyText2.html) in `TextTheme`:

> The default text style for **Material**.

Now the answer is quite clear. If your `Text` widget does not have any explicitly given text style, and has no **inherited** text style from its ancestors in the way of placing a `DefaultTextStyle` at some nodes. Then it would use the value in `bodyText2` from the theme.

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer. You're right in that `bodyText2` is used in scenarios when no text style is specified. However, it seems to be an unintuitive default; and it would be nice if there was some more information as to _why_ this style is default and whether it was picked based on some cultural or logical principle.

Answer (score 0):

You are read documentation related to themes here : https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/themes

They have explained with example.

Comment: As per previous comment; these docs don't explain why `bodyText2` is used for an unstyled widget. Which default styles are used in which situation is a bit of a black box.